# mapStateToProps is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to fetch data from json file and then render it on the screen with React and Redux. JSX is standart, I used the `<Provide>` tag and set `store` value to my store. `mapStateToProps` is going `undefined` for `this.props` as well as `toTakeData()`.

Here I have action file with request:

```
let data = {
    loading: true,
    items: [],
    prevName: null,
    selectedProfile: '',
    term: ''
}

export function getItems() {
    getRequest();
    return {
        type: 'GET_ITEMS',
        payload: data
    }
}

const getRequest = async () => {

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/item')
        .then( response => response.json() )
        .then( json => {
            data.items = json;
            data.selectedProfile = json[0];
            data.loading = false;
            data.prevName = json[0].general.firstName + ' ' + json[0].general.lastName;
        } )
        .catch( err => console.error( err ) );

}
```

And here is component file which suppose to render data:

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        console.log(state.items);
        return {
            items: state.items,
            prevName: state.prevName,
            selectedProfile: state.selectedProfile,
            term: state.term,
            loading: state.loading
        };
    };

    const mapActionsToProps = {
        toTakeData: getItems
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(SelectMenu);
```

Comment: your reducer should not make a request. move that request to an action file and dispatch from the action the data that you need to give to the reducer. Also **DO NOT MUTATE STATE DIRECTLY**. in your reducer you should be returning a new object with a piece you change, not directly mutate the values of your state

Comment: Your reducer implementation violates the basic requirement to any reducer: it is **not pure**. It is async, it makes network request and finally it mutates the state. Plz read [this](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) before you actually continue with redux. It'll help a lot.

Comment: @JohnRuddell did all u said, but it's not working

Comment: Ok can you post a codepen with what you have and i can take a look?

Comment: @JohnRuddell if I'll combine it all in one file it will work but I need to setup it with many files, so I can't post it to codepen (as I know there is only 1 file allowed)

Comment: you can do a gist or whatever... Its just basically impossible for me to give you advise / help without seeing the issue in the code

Comment: @JohnRuddell https://github.com/BakuganXD/Test-React

Comment: ok you have a lot of issues. biggest thing though is you aren't understanding how react works in terms of timing.. in the constructor this.props doesn't exist because super will run and process that async. setting the style of something as well cant happen because render hasn't happened... i'll make a PR to your repo

Comment: hmm can't push to your branch because of permissions. How do you want me to share this with you?

Comment: @JohnRuddell give me your nickname

Comment: actually here this is easier.. here is a google drive link with the changes i made. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zqMDC28vM_GGFh1jM8LZn8nPw95S-mZv?usp=sharing One thing to note.. make sure you install your dependencies again before running, i added a package `redux-thunk` for the dispatch middleware to work correctly

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thank you a lot, u saved me, I'll check tomorrow!

Comment: Glad i can help :) good luck with your coding adventures :)